# Trouble retrieving and passing data from alertdialog to listview

Tags: java, android, android-listview, android-alertdialog

Can someone help me with the code below?

The issue I am having is that the line `selectedPlayer.setScore(mScore);` runs before the user enters the data into the alert dialog.

Is there a way to modify my code so that score can be updated after the user enters the data into the alert dialog?

I feel that the `arrayPlayers` is trapped because it is declared and populated inside the fragment's onCreateView. Is there a way around this?

```
public class ScoringActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

DialogFragment mDialog;
static int mScore;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_scoring);

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment())
                .commit();
    }
}

public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

    ArrayList<Player> arrayPlayers;
    ListView listViewPlayers;
    PlayerAdapter adapter;

    public PlaceholderFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        arrayPlayers = new ArrayList<Player>();

        Intent intent = getActivity().getIntent();
        int players = intent.getIntExtra("intPlayers", 0);

        for (int i = 0; i<players; i++){
            arrayPlayers.add(new Player("player " + i, 0));
        }

        adapter = new PlayerAdapter(getActivity(), arrayPlayers);


        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_activity_scoring, container, false);

        listViewPlayers = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.listview_playerscore);
        listViewPlayers.setAdapter(adapter);

        listViewPlayers.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long l) {
                Player selectedPlayer = arrayPlayers.get(position);
                String playerName = selectedPlayer.getName();

                ((ScoringActivity)getActivity()).showDialogFragment(playerName);

                selectedPlayer.setScore(mScore);

            }
        });

        return rootView;
    }

    public void refresh() {
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

}

void showDialogFragment(String playerName) {
    mDialog = ScoreAlertDialogFragment.newInstance(playerName);
    mDialog.show(getFragmentManager(),"SCORE DIALOG");

}

// Class that creates the AlertDialog
public static class ScoreAlertDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {

    public static ScoreAlertDialogFragment newInstance(String playerName) {
        ScoreAlertDialogFragment alertFragment = new ScoreAlertDialogFragment();
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString("PlayerName", playerName);
        alertFragment.setArguments(bundle);
        return alertFragment;
    }

    // Build AlertDialog using AlertDialog.Builder
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Get the layout inflater
        LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();

        final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.alertdialog_score, null);

        final EditText editTextScore = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.edittext_score);

        return new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())
                // Inflate and set the layout for the dialog
                // Pass null as the parent view because its going in the dialog layout
                .setView(view)

                .setMessage("Enter " + getArguments().getString("PlayerName") + "'s Score:")

                //Set up Yes Button
                .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(final DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        mScore = Integer.parseInt(editTextScore.getText().toString().trim());
                    }
                })

                .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        ScoreAlertDialogFragment.this.getDialog().cancel();
                    }
                })

                .create();
    }
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    PlaceholderFragment placeholderFragment = (PlaceholderFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.container); //getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.p);
    placeholderFragment.refresh();
}
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: But it run just after the click?

Comment: The `mscore` variable is updated after the click but `selectedPlayer.setScore(mScore);` does not run after the click so the score is never updated with the user input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should pass `selectedPlayer` as an argument in `.showDialogFragment()`, rather than the playerName, which can be retrieved within the method. Then place a global variable `player` in the `ScoreAlertDialogFragment` and place the `player.setScore()` in the `onClick`.

```
listViewPlayers.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long l) {
            Player selectedPlayer = arrayPlayers.get(position);
            ((ScoringActivity)getActivity()).showDialogFragment(selectedPlayer);
        }
});

void showDialogFragment(Player player) {
    mDialog = new ScoreAlertDialogFragment(player);
    mDialog.show(getFragmentManager(),"SCORE DIALOG");
}

public static class ScoreAlertDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {

     Player player;

     public ScoreAlertDialogFragment(Player player) {
         ..
         this.player = player;
     }


 ..
.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(final DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    score = Integer.parseInt(editTextScore.getText().toString().trim());
                    player.setScore(score);
                }
            })
```

Comment: Thanks for this!

I tried it out and `this.player = player;` can not be referenced from a static context. 

Could you please advise?

Comment: I made the global variable `player` in the `ScoreAlertDialogFragment` static and it has worked! Thank you!

Comment: @timatoe No you shouldn't make `player` static, because it doesn't have the characteristics of a static variable. A better solution would be replacing `newInstance()` with a constructor. I updated the post.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to put `selectedPlayer.setScore(mScore);` in the onclicklistener of the Dialog? You could send the selectedPlayer as parameter to the Dialog if needed.

Comment: Hi, I have tried this but I am having/had trouble with sending selectedPlayer as a parameter.

Answer (score 0):

```
 ((ScoringActivity)getActivity()).showDialogFragment(selectedPlayer,view);
```

change score inside and set the score using the view 
ie 
you will get the parent from the view 
view.getParent();
try to set the text from their.